# Number of different bijections between a set $S$ with $n$ elements and itself

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I am trying to solve exercise 2.1 in Aluffi's textbook "Chapter 0":

> How many different bijections are there between a set $S$ with $n$ elements and itself?

Here is my attempt. My "non-rigorous" answer is that I can make the function injective by choosing $n$ elements for where to make the first element of $S$, $n-1$ possibilities for the second, and so forth, giving $n!$ functions. Then this is a function injective function from $S$ to $S$ which is finite, so it is immediately surjective. (I don't think surjectivity just "follows" without invoking this kind of obvious, though it sounds obvious that it's surjective, though it's somewhat tough to prove.) Here is my attempt at making the argument rigorous, but I'd appreciate feedback on this above sketch as well.

> Since there are $|n|$ choices for where to send each $s_i \in S$, there are exactly $n^n$ functions $f: S \to S$. If $f(s_1) = f(s_2)$ for $s_1 \neq s_2$, then $\mathrm{Im}(f) \not \subset S$, i.e., its cardinality is $< n$, so it is not surjective; furthermore, it is not injective. There are $n!$ mappings $S \to S$ with no repeated inputs or repeated outputs, which are the only bijections $S \to S$.

How does this look? Are there ways to make it more rigorous?

Comment: The answer is $n!$, for essentially the reasons you provide.

Comment: Am I missing anything? As I said I don't believe my answer is fully rigorous, so I'd appreciate any pointers on how to better word it.

Comment: Look at the linked proof to see how to do it more rigorously.

Comment: The linked proof gives that injectivity implies surjectivity and vice-versa for a function on a finite set $S$. I get this, and don't have a problem with the proof. After taking this result for granted, I'm not sure if the remainder of my proof is sufficiently rigorous. Am I correct that I'm really "counting all the injections" with the counting method I described?

Comment: I don't really see that you've used a counting method, except for the case when surjectivity and injectivity are disregarded (and you got $n^n$).  You just sort of claim that the right answer is $n!$.  That's true but one can justify it, e.g. by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative (much less elegant) approach.

Label the elements in $S:~~~s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n$.

Let $P$ denote the $(n^n)$ possible mappings from $S$ onto itself.
Let $Q$ denote the subset of $P$ that consist of all bijections from $S$ onto itself.

Let $N = \{1,2,3,\cdots, n\}.$
Let $A$ denote the $(n^n)$ possible mappings from $N$ onto itself.
Let $B$ denote the subset of $A$ that represents all of the bijections from $N$ to $N$.
Let $C$ denote the subset of $A$ that represents all of the ways of permuting the numbers in $N$.

Per [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation):

- $C$ has exactly $(n!)$ elements.
- $C = B \implies B$ has exactly $(n!)$ elements.

Consider the mapping $\lambda: P \to A$ defined as follows:
For any $p \in P, ~a = \lambda(p)$ is defined as follows:
$a(i) = j \iff p(s_i) = s_j.$

Take any $q \in Q$, and let $a = \lambda(q).$  Since $q$ is a bijection, you know that

- For each element $s_j \in N$, there is exactly one element $s_i \in N$ such that $q(s_i) = s_j.$

Per the definition of $\lambda$, this implies that

- For each element $j \in N$, there is exactly one element $i \in N$ such that $a(i) = j.$

Therefore, $a$ is a bijection from $N$ to $N$.
Therefore, $a \in B$.
Therefore, $\lambda(Q)~$ [i.e. the set of all $\lambda(q)$, where $q \in Q$] is a subset of $B.$

Let $~~b~~$ be any element in $B$, which implies that $b$ is a bijection from $N$ onto itself.

Construct the element $f$ in $P$ as follows:
$f(s_i) = s_j \iff b(i) = b(j).$

Because $b$ is a bijection, you know that for each element $j$ in $N$ there is exactly one element $i$ in $N$ such that $b(i) = j.$

Because of the construction done to create $f$, you know that:

- For each element $s_j$ in $S$, there is exactly one element $s_i$ in $S$ such that $f(s_i) = s_j$.  This implies that $f$ is a bijection from $S$ to $S$.  Therefore, $f$ is in $Q$.
- $\lambda(f) = b$.

Therefore, $\lambda(Q) = B.$

Let $\lambda'$ represent the mapping $\lambda$ with its domain restricted to $Q$.

Then, since $\lambda(Q) = B, ~\lambda'$ is a surjection from $Q$ onto $B$.

Further, per the definition of $\lambda$, it is immediate that $\lambda$ is injective.  That is, you can't have two distinct elements $f_1, f_2 \in P$ such that $\lambda(f_1) = \lambda(f_2).$

Consequently, $\lambda'$ inherits the property of being an injection.  Therefore, $\lambda'$ is a bijection from the finite set $Q$ to the finite set $B$.
Therefore, since $B$ has $(n!)$ elements, so does $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

There are  $n $ choices for the first element,  $n-1$ for the second etc...  So $n!$.

Personally I think it *is* obvious that a surjection, or injection,  which is an endomorphism on a finite set, is a bijection.

(But some may question my rigor here, I guess.)

Comment: It's obvious to me that it's an injection by construction (we drop one choice each time), but not necessarily that it's a surjection. Is there an intuitive reason that's the case? Or is it just the fact that $f: S \to S$ is injective iff surjective when $S$ is finite?

Comment: There's  $n $ elements,  so only $n $ to drop.  This might be an example of the  "pigeonhole principle".